# boost::dynamic_pointer_cast with const pointer not working?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, casting

Let's say I have two classes, A and B, where B is a child class of A.

I also have the following function:

```
void foo(boost::shared_ptr<const A> a)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<const B> b = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<const B>(a); // Error !
}
```

Compilation with gcc gives me the following errors:

```
C:\Boost\include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: In constructor 'boost::shared_ptr< <template-parameter-1-1> >::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<Y>&, boost::detail::dynamic_cast_tag) [with Y = const A, T = const B]':
C:\Boost\include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:522:   instantiated from 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::dynamic_pointer_cast(const boost::shared_ptr<U>&) [with T = const B, U = const A]'
src\a.cpp:10:   instantiated from here
C:\Boost\include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:259: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'r->boost::shared_ptr<const A>::px' (of type 'const class A* const') to type 'const class B*' (source type is not polymorphic)
```

What could possibly be wrong ?

Thank you.

#### EDIT

Actually, I found out how to avoid this, but I'm not sure to understand.

My `A` class was empty (and thus had no virtual destructor). If I add a virtual destructor, the error goes out. But I don't get it, why is this required ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`dynamic_pointer_cast` uses the C++ `dynamic_cast` internally and `dynamic_cast` requires your classes to have at least one virtual method. No virtual methods means no vtable and without vtable `dynamic_cast` would not be able to figure which casts are doable at run-time.

Comment: +1 This is mandated in 5.2.7/6 in the standard: "Otherwise, v shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type (10.3)."

Comment: @sbk So it could be the destructor, or any other method. It just needs to be virtual. Did I get this right ?

Comment: Yes, virtual destructor is fairly common anyway for a base class.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use `dynamic_cast` on a `Type*` pointer if `Type` is a class with at least one virtual member function (virtual destructor counts). Since `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast` uses `dynamic_cast` internally the same restriction applies to it as well.